# How to add click on the action bar back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add click functionality on the `Actionbar` back button. I have tried the below things till now, but unable to get the desired result.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Observed that the onClick method is not being called when i click  on the back button in the action bar

```
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
    };

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    drawer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toggle.syncState();
        }
    });
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onKeyDown(4, null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your Activity code .

Comment: Post your showToast() method

Comment: Make sure you have added Toast.show();

Comment: What you are getting in "id" @arun

Answer (score 0):

Use the updated code

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            showToast("Test");
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code inside your Activity :

```
//for going back or finish current activity.


       @Override
        public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
```

Below code are for actionBar menu.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.logout) {
         // toast Here
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.home) {
         // toast Here
        return true;
    }




    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is used for creating your menu & setting your menu.xml

`onOptionsItemSelected()` is used for selection of menu items & actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            }
    });
```

Comment: you have created tool bar

Comment: yes,i applied the same code, but observed that onclick is not being called.

Comment: My below method not getting called.

Comment: toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onKeyDown(4, null);
            }
        });